# Loading specifc field from row using array_filter and array_slice, want to empty field afterwards

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a pretty complicated issue here. Let me first try to explain it in words. I am inserting 100 keywords and 100 URL's in a database table, using fields named url_01, url_02, url_03, anchor_01, anchor_02, anchor_03 etc.

Now I want to pick the first URL/anchor combination and I manage to do that using a combination of `array_filter` and `array_slice` like this:

```
$anchor=current(array_filter(array_slice($gig,5)));
$url=current(array_filter(array_slice($gig,105)));
```

The reason I slice it at position 5 is cause the other fields should be ignored, and anchor_01 ranges till anchor_00 at the end, so at position 105 my url fields start. This works fine and it provides me with the url/anchor combo while skipping empty fields.

The reason I use `current(array_filter)` is cause I want to erase the anchor/url combo from the database after it has been used and this allows me to take the first entry while ignoring empty spots, while the slice makes sure I start after my other keys.

However, when I made this I only thought about how to pull it from the database, not how to erase it.

So my question: Is there a way to find out that it are those two I want to erase and not any of the others?

Or is there a much better way where I can first insert a list of 100 url's and 100 anchors, and make sure I always get a unique value from the database, as each entry may only be used once, and preferebly I see it erased after that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I am not able to erase the previous value but I am able to select the right field by adding a counter like this:

```
$counting=$gig['count'];
$anchor=current(array_filter(array_slice($gig,6+$counting)));
$url=current(array_filter(array_slice($gig,106+$counting)));

if($server_date>$post_date) {
   $add_count=$counting+1;
   $sql_date="UPDATE `wp_backlinks` SET count='".$add_count."' WHERE id=".$client_id;
   $result = $wpdb->query($sql_date);
} else { echo 'WAIT'; }
```

Easy fix, still I tend to think there are better ways to accomplish this in php?